# How to remove extra margin space generated by inline blocks?

Tags: css

The markup is here:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

* {margin: 0; padding:0;}
ul{ border: 1px solid black; height: 100px;width:100%; display:block;} 
li{display:inline-block;width: 200px; height: 100px; background: red;}
```

you can see the demo in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5KDZG/2/)

My confuse is, I have already set all the margin and padding into zero, why there is still gap here? Until I have to set the `float: left` to clear the gap

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this html

```
<ul>
     <li></li><!--
  --><li></li><!--
  --><li></li>
</ul>
```

working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/5KDZG/6/)**

***Also*** you can find explanation and another solutions in this css-tricks article: **[Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)**

Answer (score 0):

Now just add this css in your stylesheet

```
ul{
font-size:0;
}
ul li{
font-size:12px; // according to your design 
}
```

**[*Live Demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/5KDZG/3/)**

### ------

**If you set the all li in one line than define this**

```
ul{
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

***[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5KDZG/5/)***